# Adding the nth character of every string in an array to another array's nth list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Having some serious trouble with this, even though this seems extremely basic.

I have two lists; one that is two dimensional, with four total lists inside of it, all of which contain four characters in string format. The another one is also two dimensional with four total lists, but the lists are empty.

```
list1 = [['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]
list2 = [[], [], [], []]
```

So, what I'm trying to do is iterating through list1's lists, and adding the nth character of every list to the nth list inside list2.

What it *should* look like afterwards: (an example)

```
list1 = [['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]
list2 = [['aaaa'], ['bbbb'], ['cccc'], ['dddd']]
```

What I have tried:

```
i = 0
n = 0
while n < 4:
    for list in list1:
        list2[n] += list[i][n] # n = nth character
    n += 1
```

First off, I have to admit I have zero idea what [i] does here, or why it even works in the first place; if I replace [i] with [0], it stops working and returns an index error.

What it outputs:

```
list2 = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd']]
```

How should I change the code to get the string in the format mentioned above?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `'abcd'` is inside a redundant list? i.e. why not do `list1 = ['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd']`

Comment: What is `n` here?

Comment: `# n = nth character`

Comment: `list2=[["".join([sublist[0][i] for _ in range(len(list1))])] for i, sublist in enumerate(list1)]` for example? Although I'm really not sure what your lists usually look like so not sure what metric to use where

Comment: It would help if you provided an input -> output example that didn't use the same four letters, or some context.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I saw you deleted your answer. It looks good to me, just change the i to a `0`. Then again, I have been doing chemistry homework for the past two hours, so I may just be missing something obvious :-)

Comment: @NilsWerner This is part of an assignment on my CS-course, and the use of an array is pretty much required.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute Sorry, it's part of an assignment on my CS-course, where we have to create a basic tic-tac-toe program. The array stores the values of the grid, and this is the part where the grid checks for possible wins on a vertical axis. Sorry for not providing more info, I find my question embarrassing when given the context...

Comment: `list1` in your example is actually _three_ dimensional because strings are sequences, too, just like a list—so it's a list of lists of strings. Given that your stated goal makes little sense as a consequence of the observation in @Nils Werner's comment.

Comment: It would be clearer what you want if you changed the example to `list1 = [['abcd'], ['efgh'], ['ijkl'], ['mnop']]`. The way you have it now, it's impossible to tell what the source was of the letters that end up in the strings in `list2`. Also, should/can we assume that `list2` will always be initialized with the same number of second-level sublists as the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function on `list2` to get what you need:

```
list1 = [['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]
list2 = [[], [], [], []]

i = 0
n = 0
while n < 4:
    for sub_list in list1:
        list2[n] += sub_list[i][n] # n = nth character
    n += 1

list2 = [[''.join(listx)] for listx in list2]
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I tried something similar earlier with a for-loop, but got rather weird outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]
list2 = [[], [], [], []]
final_list = [[a[i]*4] for i, [[a], b] in enumerate(zip(list1, list2))]
```

Output:

```
[['aaaa'], ['bbbb'], ['cccc'], ['dddd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `list2[n] +=` adds an element to the list that `list2[n]` is. Instead you want to create a string. Note that you have no string initially to append to.

As your purpose is to add the *same* character repeatedly, you should not have to design a loop for that. You can use the `*` operator for that.

```
for i, list in enumerate(list1):
    list2[i].append(list[0][i] * 4)
```

NB: If you want to overwrite `list2` with the result, then look to some of the other answers. This answer will mutate the original `list2` in-place.

Comment: Not the same character, I used the same characters as only an example; thank you for your help, though!

Comment: OK, a pity that you did not provide a better case in your question then.

Comment: Well, the question was "adding the nth character of every string in an array to another array's nth list", not "adding the same character four times from a list to another list" @trincot

Comment: Yes, but that can be interpreted in different ways. A good example can take that possibility away. For example, your code meets the question (the character *is* added to a list), but you were apparently looking for another interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I did a minor change in your code:

```
list1 = [['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]
list2 = [[], [], [], []]

i = 0
n = 0
while n < 4:
    for l in list1:
        string = "".join(l[i][n] * len(l[0])) # Changed line
    list2[n] = [string] # Placed assignment out of 'for' loop
    n += 1

print(list2)
```

The output is:

```
[['aaaa'], ['bbbb'], ['cccc'], ['dddd']]
```